# Accessing input name array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dom

I have the following HTML form

```
<form action="#" method="post">

 <table>
 <tr>  
  <td><label>Product:<label> <input type="text" /></td>
  <td><label>Price:<label> <input type="text" /></td>
  <td><label>Quantity:<label> <input type="text"/></td>
  <td><label>Amount:<label> <input type="text" name="amount[]"/></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>  
 <td><label>Product:<label> <input type="text" /></td>
 <td><label>Price:<label> <input type="text" /></td>
 <td><label>Quantity:<label> <input type="text"/></td>
 <td><label>Amount:<label> <input type="text" name="amount[]"/></td>
 </tr>

 <!---only two rows have been created by the user -->


 <input type="button" value="Add product" onClick="addProductRow()"/> 
 <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </table>  
</form>
```

The input fields are created dynamically by the user(there is button for adding a row to the page). When user adds the price and the quantity the amount(price*quantity) has to be displayed in the relevant amount field.

My problem is, how can i access each amount field to insert the total amount using JavaScript or jQuery.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do in this case is use `parentNode` until you get to the containing `<tr>`, and then use that table row node to search for the input fields.

Answer (score 0):

You should also add an ID to each field (an array-name like `quantityfields[]` and `pricefields[]` works too) and use the standard `document.getElementById("quantityfields[0]")`

I have also seen `document.getElementsByName(name)` which will return an array which you can traverse and do your own thing, and you wouldn't have to use an extra ID, but I think `getElementById` is more common.

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery (in case you have no ids and there is only one table on the page)

```
var total;
$("table").find("tr").each(function(index, elem){
    total = total + parseInt($("td:eq(3) input", this).val());
});
```